# Ajax JS/PHP Image Uploader not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-data

I tried multiple approaches and followed quite a lot questions in StkOvfl, and W3 Specifications, but still no idea.

I have a form input:

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" id="item-image-upload" >
```

Then in my Javascript (`prepareFormData` method): [[See full gist class here]](https://gist.github.com/tikaPahadi/441b06d47ce457e6dc57):

```
    var files = this.getFiles();
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        var file = files[i];

        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        formData.append(this.uploadEntityName, file);
    }
```

When I `console.log(files),` I get all the files all fine. But, formData is not working. I also tried adding an arbitrary item as:

```
    formData.append("Apple", 1);
```

The response I get is empty. The server does repose in php as:

```
public function uploadImage(){
    return json_encode(array_merge($_REQUEST, $_FILES));
}
```

Comment: Does the `formData.append("Apple", 1)` also not work?

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea then. Liked the Gist though.

Comment: Does your form tag include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah "The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data". <- https://devdocs.io/dom/formdata

Comment: I've done similar things, and the only difference I can see looking at my working code is I didn't manually set the header, and I passed a (faked) filename as a third argument to `formData.append`

Comment: Okay. Next I would like to remove the `if (!file.type.match('image.*'))` condition to ensure that's not the issue. It may be "image/*" instead.

Comment: is `this.uploadEntityName` on line #60 getting set somewhere not in the gist?

Comment: @aron.duby, I updated the gist. In fact, the original JS class is quite big and I cut off some irrelevant methods there. I also tried `formData.append(this.uploadEntityName, file, file.name);` No help there.  @RaphaelRafatpanah, Tried that. Still No help. I also have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It even does not work on `Apple = 1`. Response Code is still `200` and responds a dummy array on server as it when I dump it.

Comment: @tika Use a `console.log( formData.get(this.uploadEntityName) )` after [L61](https://gist.github.com/tikaPahadi/441b06d47ce457e6dc57#file-imageuploader-js-L61)

Comment: when you say the response is empty, do you mean there's absolutely no response or the response is `[]`?

Comment: @aron.duby `[]` perfectly sensing that `$_REQUEST` is empty.

Comment: @hjpotter92 `Uncaught TypeError: formData.get is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm 99% sure now that it's your header, and that if you look in your logs, or turn on PHP Warnings you'll see `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0`

I copied this (and added your header line and removed the input file) from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and ran it on a script on my dev box that is set to shout all errors and I got that error, followed by an empty array

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("somefiles[]", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "MYDEVBOX/testpost.php");
// remove the line below and it works
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.responseType = "json";
request.send(formData);
```

Back a few minutes later after deciding to look into why. It has to do with the boundary of the multi-part data. The XHR is automatically setting the header with matching boundary when you do `xhr.send(formData)` (or somewhere along the way). When you set that header, the request uses that instead, wiping out the boundary and PHP doesn't know where to split the input. Here's a quick screen cap that points it out much better.

[image]

Comment: Let me test. Thanks though.

Comment: just did an edit after digging into why a bit more, made perfect sense once I dug into it in the network panel

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. I was doing the un-necessary headers.